# How to select a random string from a list

Tags: java, string, random

I'm trying to create a program which stimulates picking a card from a deck. I've tried to use the `Random` class to pick the `suit` and the `rank` but I can't get it working. This is my code so far.

```
   String[] rank = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",  "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
   int idx = new Random().nextInt(rank.length);
   String random = (rank[idx]);

   String[] suit = {"Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};
   int idx = new Random().nextInt(suit.length);
   String random = (suit[idx]);

   System.out.println("The card you picked is " + Arrays.toString(rank) + " of " + Arrays.toString(suit));
```

I'm sure it's very simple but I'm relatively new to Java so any help is appreciated!

Comment: **"but I can't get it working"** you can do better than this :)

Comment: You have 2 variables with the same name idx,random and you are printing out the wrong variable, should be the 2 random values.

Comment: You're repeating your variables,  `idx` and `random` use a different name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did it correctly. You just need to print the right variables:

```
String[] rank =  // ...
int rankIndex = new Random().nextInt(rank.length);
String randomRank = rank[rankIndex];

String[] suit = // ...
int suitIndex = new Random().nextInt(suit.length);
String randomSuit = suit[suitIndex];

System.out.println("The card you picked is " + randomRank + " of " + randomSuit);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here: `System.out.println("The card you picked is " + Arrays.toString(rank) + " of " + Arrays.toString(suit));`. You are printing your complete list of items each time.

What you need to do is to place `(rank[idx])` and `(suit[idx]);` into string variables and print those.

```
    String[] rank = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
    int idx = new Random().nextInt(rank.length);
    String randomRank = (rank[idx]);

    String[] suit = {"Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};
    idx = new Random().nextInt(suit.length);
    String randomSuit = (suit[idx]);
    System.out.println("The card you picked is " + randomRank + " of " + randomSuit);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure to add what's wrong, you haven't included what problem you are having.

But I'm expecting it's the following:

1) String random is declared twice
2) Arrays.toString() is not needed

```
System.out.println("The card you picked is " + **Arrays.toString(rank)** + " of " + Arrays.toString(suit));
```

Why are you using Arrays.ToString()?

```
 String rankstr = (rank[idx]);
 String suitStr = (suit[idx]);
    System.out.println("The card you picked is " + rankStr + " of " + suitStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're repeating the variables names `idx` and `random`, choose different names and output like this:

```
System.out.println("The card you picked is " +random2+ " of " +random);
//The card you picked is 2 of Spades
```

---

**Live Java Example:**

http://ideone.com/9asht6